# Constantly re-entering Apple ID on AirPort Extreme

Tags: apple-id, airport

We have a MacBook, iMac, two iPads, and two iPhones, all of them using the same Apple ID with no complaint.  But the AirPort Extreme says "incorrect Apple ID or password" every time I look at the Airport Assistant.  I re-enter ID and password, and they are accepted every time—status turns green.  Then within two hours, it is amber again and claiming invalid ID or password.

All six devices have the latest O.S. or firmware.  The WiFi continues to work through the error.

Why?  Corrective action?

Comment: look at which assistant? My airport is pretty much set & forget, no Apple ID required.

Comment: Airport Assistant.  "Set and forget" is what I expect.  For the Apple authentication to succeed and then fail without being touched is really weird.

Comment: Wasn‘t the Apple ID on an Extreme only required to enable Back To My Mac?

Comment: @nohillside, that is correct.  It is also (I think) irrelevant to an authentication succeeding, and then declaring otherwise soon after.

Comment: Apple may have turned something off related to that, who knows.

Comment: Well, they did discontinue the AirPort Extreme long ago.  Yet last month, the latest firmware was still available for update.  And pretty strange for the authentication to succeeded and then for it to “change its mind”—to say “incorrect ID or password” shortly after.